# URL Rewrite/Redirection Not Working Using htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am on Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server and I am hosting a site with 5 php static pages.

I want the urls to be permanently appear as `example.com/page1/` instead of `example.com/page1.php`.

Also want to show `404 error message` while accessing `example.com/page1.php`

I am using the code below and getting `404 error`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php
    RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/?$ privacy-policy.php
    RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php
</IfModule>
```

Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Format corrections

Answer (score 0):

the code you provided is correct for removing the file extension.
what you want can be achieved by:-

Redirection to custom page:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Run Php without filename extension
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

    # Return 404 if original request is .php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
    RewriteRule .* new.php
</IfModule>
```

Redirection to default page:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Run Php without filename extension
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

    # Return 404 if original request is .php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
</IfModule>
```

hope this helps :-)